# testing ERRORLEVEL in a batch file doesn't return the expected result

Tags: batch-file

I have a Windows 7 x64 system where I would like to have a batch file execute a program and then test the exit code of the process and perform some action based on that exit code. For example:

```
@rem sets the process exit code to 1. should print "success!" actually prints nothing
cmd /c exit 1
if NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 echo success!

@rem prints "success!" as expected
cmd /c exit 1
if errorlevel 1 echo success!

@rem prints "failure!" even though the exit code is 0
cmd /c exit 0
if errorlevel 1 echo failure!    

@rem prints "ERRORLEVEL=1" as expected
cmd /c exit 1
echo ERRORLEVEL=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

What do I need to do to get the expected behavior out of the batch file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOT ERRORLEVEL 0` is not working as you may think

First, it evaluates `ERRORLEVEL 0`
As the error level is **0 or greater**, this evaluates to `TRUE`

Then it evaluates the `NOT`
`NOT TRUE` is `FALSE`, which means your first message does not get printed.

Thie 3rd result doesn't echo Failure, so I don't know what is wrong on your system. To check error levels, I put `echo ERRORLEVEL=%ERRORLEVEL%` after every exit statement